# Gamma distribution: ratio of 2 CSS not containing $\beta$

Tags: self-study, gamma-distribution, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid and follow $Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, where $$f(x,\alpha, \beta)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}$$  I already showed that $\overline{X}$ and $X^*=\left[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right]^\frac{1}{n}$ are complete and sufficient statistics for $(\alpha, \beta)$.  I am to show that the distribution of the statistic $T=\frac{\overline{X}}{X^*}$ does not depend on $\beta$ but am unsure how to do so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not contain $\beta$"?  When I look at the formulae, I see no $\beta$...

Comment: I edited the wording of the problem a little bit; hopefully that clears it up. The $X_i$'s follow $Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ and I need to show that the statistic $T$ is ancillary for $\beta$.

Comment: Please mention the parameterization you are using, i.e. the pdf of Gamma(a,b).

Comment: As a hint: try a change of variable from $x$ to $y=x/\beta$.  If you solve for the distribution of $y$, you will see that it doesn't have $\beta$ as a parameter.   Then show that $\bar{Y} / Y^* = \bar{X}/X^*$, and you're essentially done.

Comment: @jbowman that was a giant help.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Because $\beta$ is a scale factor and both $\bar X$ and $X^{*}$ are homogeneous functions of degree $1,$ their ratio $T$ has degree $0:$ that is, it is invariant, *QED.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=X/\beta$.  Then,
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(y\beta)\beta=\frac{(y\beta)^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\beta y/\beta)}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}$$
$$=\frac{y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$
Note that the distribution of Y does not depend on $\beta$.  Now consider
$$\overline{Y}=\frac{\sum Y_i}{n}=\frac{\sum X_i/\beta}{n}=\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\sum X_i}{n}$$
$$Y*=\left[\prod_{i=1}^n Y_i\right]^{1/n}=\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i/\beta \right]^{1/n}=\frac{1}{\beta}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right]^{1/n}$$
Then, when taking the ratio $\frac{\overline{Y}}{Y*}$, note that the $\frac{1}{\beta}$ pieces of both statistics cancel, and you're left with $\frac{\overline{X}}{X*}$.  This tells us that the statistic $T=\frac{\overline{X}}{X*}$ does not depend on $\beta$.