# Conditional distribution of complete sufficient statistics being ancillary of $\alpha$

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, gamma-distribution, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Regarding the distribution and statistics as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459876/gamma-distribution-ratio-of-2-css-not-containing-beta), I need to show that the conditional distribution of $\overline{X}$ given $X^*=x^*$ does not depend on $\alpha$.  I remember my professor used a technique for a similar type of problem, where he looked at $P(\overline{X}=\overline{x} | X^*=x^*)$ and did some manipulation and variable changes, but I'm not finding how to apply that to this problem.  Any help or any other approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained.

Comment: The solution is to start from the joint distribution of $(\bar X,X^\star)$ and derive the conditional distribution of $\bar X$ given $X^\star$.